# Getting this error "Cannot invoke set(int, String) on the array type String[]"

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm currently working on this problem:

"1. Due to a problem with a scanner an array of words was created with spaces in incorrect places. Write the code to process the list of words and trim any spaces out of the words.

So if the list contains:

{"every", " near ing ", " checking", "food ", "stand", "value "}
  It should be changed to hold:

{"every", "nearing", "checking", "food", "stand", "value"}
  Note that this activity does not require you to print anything. Your code should end with the array list still declared and containing the resulting words."

I just had trouble navigating the string to array to list to string conversions and now I am finally at the end an I am getting this problem.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main {
        static int i=0;
        static String dang;
        public static String [] list = {};
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();

                for(String string: list){
                    if(string.indexOf(' ')!=-1){
                        char[] array = string.toCharArray();

                        for(char c: array){
                            if(c!=' '){
                                charList.add(c);
                            }
                        }
                        for(char c: charList){
                            dang+=c;
                        }


                        list.set(i,dang);
                    }
                    i++;
                }


            }
    }
```

Ignore my terrible scoping and other issues I just started giving things more scope until other parts worked and fixing things that were throwing errors. This is not being turned in just ran through a compiler with some test data to ensure it is correct so it does not need to be commented or formatted properly. The problematic code is `list.set(i,dang);`.

Comment: Look at this `public static String[] list = {};`. You should use `list[i] = dang;`. But why such a complicated approach? Just try `for (int i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++ ) {
            list[i] = list[i].replace(" ", "");
        }`

Comment: An array and a `List` are not the same thing.  I think you've confused yourself by calling your array `list`.  Calling your cat "chicken" isn't going to make it lay eggs.  The syntax for setting an element of an array requires square brackets.  Write `list[i] = dang;`.

Comment: The reason why I didn't use .replace is because I haven't learned how to use .replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String [] list = {};
... 
list.set(i,dang);
```

list(variable you are using) is array, you can not use set method here.
set method is not available in array.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense, thank you.  That part was told be entered in by the problems maker, I didn't really even look at it.  Thank you.